# .md files on github don't display same with that on markdownpad2

Tags: github, markdown

What it looks like on MarkdownPad2 software:
[image: MarkdownPad screenshot]

What it looks like on GitHub:
[image: GitHub screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to improve your question to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [numerous](https://www.w3.org/community/markdown/wiki/MarkdownImplementations) markdown engines and implementations, of which [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/categories/writing-on-github/) and [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/) are just two. While they all implement markdown with basic similarities, there are always differences.

From looking at your screenshots, it seems the main issues lie with headings and code formatting.

- For [headings](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/#headings), try adding a space after the hash symbol:

  ```
  # Foo
  ```

  not

  ```
  #Foo
  ```
- For [code blocks](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/), try wrapping the code with three backticks:

  ````
  ```
  Foo
  ```
  ````

In short, your best option is to read the GitHub markdown documentation and adjust your markdown text to fit with GitHub's formatting and syntax style.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors or not following some best practices:

1. Headings should have one space between `#` and the `Heading text`, e.g. `# Heading`
2. You should have empty line between paragraphs.
3. For code blocks, wrapping with triple back-ticks
4. Better to have only one top level header
5. Better to put empty lines around `heading line` to make your file easy to read.

You should get familiar with the Github Flavored Markdown (GFM) first. Suggest to read these links first [Mastering Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) and [Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

Comment: No need to put empty lines before or after the heading line; the `#` is all that's required.

Comment: Thanks @CodeMacabre. Yes you're right. My editor complains me if I don't put empty lines there. I've a Markdown Linter configured.